# Amazon SQS for bounce and complaint notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

I'm setting up a project in ASP.NET C# to manage the bounces and complaints notification when I send massive emails with Amazon SES.

I've read around that the best way, for large amount of messages, is SQS and not the simpler SNS on HTTP endpoint.

I've found some ready code by Amazon Team: 
https://sesblog.amazon.com/post/TxJE1JNZ6T9JXK/Handling-Bounces-and-Complaints

I've understood that SQS service must be called by me, is not pushing like SNS, but I don't understand how I have to call it, which URL and how to build the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SQS console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/sqs/.
2. Create a Queue. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/CreatingQueue.html
3. Select the queue to which you want to subscribe an Amazon SNS topic.
4. Select **Subscribe Queue to SNS Topic** from the **Queue Actions** drop-down list.
5. From the Choose a Topic drop-down list, select an Amazon SNS topic to subscribe the queue to and then click Subscribe.
6. In the Topic Subscription Result dialog box, click OK.

You can verify the results of the topic's queue subscription by publishing to the topic and viewing the message that the topic sends to the queue. For detailed steps, see Test it out by publishing a message to the topic and reading the message from the queue.